# How to get the popup dialog box text field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one popup dialog box,in that dialog box ,i have added one text field.now onclicking the add button,i want to get the text box value and i want to post that value into another asp page.iam not getting how do it..

Here is my code.

Button code:-

```
<asp:Button ID="button2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Add" />
<div>
<div id="popup" style="display:none">    
            Name:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coname" runat="server" /> 

</div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript code     .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){
        $("#button2").click(function () {
            $("#popup").dialog({
                title: "Name",
                width: 430,
                height: 250,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Add: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    })
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should just do something more than just "close dialog" in your Add part...

Try first, something like :

```
//... JS Add : function()  part
console.log($('#coname').val());
$(this).dialog('close');
```

This displays the user's entry...
If you have to do something with it, then just handle it there before closing the dialog^^

Comment: Thanks..How can i post that value into another asp page?

Comment: You could maybe use your popup dialog as a "Form" with action to your asp page ! (for example) :) (Build a "standard" form, put it in your popup, and submit button action is to post the form to a specific action page... ) got it?  :)